# "This box of matches is empty"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, noun-phrases

There are several Japanese books teaching Japanese students how to write in English. I found this example in [『英作文参考書の誤りを正す』](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E8%8B%B1%E4%BD%9C%E6%96%87%E5%8F%82%E8%80%83%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%AE%E8%AA%A4%E3%82%8A%E3%82%92%E6%AD%A3%E3%81%99-%E6%B2%B3%E4%B8%8A-%E9%81%93%E7%94%9F/dp/4469241512) (*Correcting Errors in English Composition Manuals*) by Michio Kawakami and J.D. Monkman.

The authors of this book claim that this sentence is incorrect:

> This box of matches is empty.

They note that a “box of matches” is a box containing matches (and not a box made for keeping matches), hence the sentence should instead be:

> This *matchbox* is empty.

Likewise, an “empty bottle of beer” should instead be an “empty beer bottle.”

Is this actually an error that I should avoid in writing English? If so, is it a grammatical error or something else?

Comment: If this isn't a peeve then it must be either General Reference or it should be asked on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Pedantically:  It is a matchbox, not a box of matches.  But, box of matches is universally understood to be a matchbox whether empty or not.  Of can mean *for* in this sense.

Comment: Wow. Why is everybody making such a big deal about this? It's really very straightforward. The sentence is grammatical. It even makes sense. A box of matches doesn't necessarily have to have matches in it to be intended to be a box of matches.

Comment: I'll be the odd one out, then, and agree (in essence, though not in detail) with the author of the book. “This box of matches is empty” is obviously perfectly fine _grammatically_, but it is as strange semantically to me as “This bottle of beer has only milk in it” or “This plate of pancakes is served in a bowl”. It is understandable, of course, but it made me frown and threw me, too, and my immediate thought was, “Well, it's not a box of matches then, is it?”.

Comment: It's an empty box of matches. Just as you can have a bottle of wine that no longer contains wine, or a tin of biscuits with only one biscuit, so too you can have a box of matches with no matches.

Comment: ivanhoescott: To me it's Off Topic General Reference/common knowledge among native speakers that people can and do say things such as [*the bottle of wine was empty*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22bottle+of+wine+was+empty%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Normal use of English isn't always logical, and there's certainly nothing wrong *grammatically*, so I stand by my first comment (and @Mitch's as well! :)

Comment: I think I tracked down the reference work that the question is asking about, so I edited it into the question. I also made the changes that I recommended in previous comments. Please check them for accuracy at your leisure, ivanhoescott. My apologies if I was abrasive or annoying yesterday.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet. I tend to agree that _matchbox_ and _beer bottle_ sound better, but having never seen a box made out of matches or a bottle made out of beer/wine, I would disagree with the text.  In fact, I would argue that to teach such a rigid interpretation is a mistake, though entertaining.

Comment: I had upvoted your post days ago. :) -- Your question involves the preposition "of", which can be considered to be the default preposition, and which is often used in many different ways, because, er, because it is the default preposition. And so, er, the preposition "of" isn't limited to those few meanings that your textbook (authors) is saying it is. The meaning of "of" depends on the context, and on the intent of the writer/speaker. If you are really interested in this topic, you probably should access vetted grammar sources, such as a reference grammar.

Comment: @ivanhoescott They may have just meant that it was wrong because it sounded funny, not because it violated any grammatical rules.

Comment: In this case, we have a very convenient alternative: *matchbox*. But what if you've just been robbed and want to say *"the bag of Spanish reales is empty"*. Would the authors have you say *"the Spanish reales bag is empty"*? While *"matchbox"* a reasonable (in fact, preferable) alternative, *"Spanish reales bag"* is not.

Comment: Would anyone consider using [empty] 'bottle of milk' for an empty milk bottle?

Answer (score 20):

Most native English speakers would find nothing strange about an “empty box of matches” or an “empty bottle of beer.” They would readily interpret these phrases as a “box [for] matches” or perhaps a “bottle [previously full] of beer.”

If you pointed out that “empty matchbox” or “empty beer bottle” is preferable, a fluent English speaker might agree, or might just shrug and wonder what the big deal is about. Diction choices like this are a matter of **style,** and poor choices are **style errors.** Most rules of style are subjective, so what looks like a style error to one writer (like the authors of your reference book) might be perfectly acceptable to another. One of the functions of a **[style guide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Style_guide)** is to recommend specific choices for diction, spelling, punctuation, formatting, *etc.* to maintain a consistent style in publications.

Note that this construction is not a [grammatical error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar#Use_of_the_term), at least not as the term is used by linguists. Jeremy Butterfield aptly notes that “Grammar is often a generic way of referring to any aspect of English that people object to.” While linguists and other serious language enthusiasts use *grammar* to mean a variety of things, it generally relates to the structure of language rather than its meaning. Thus, phrases like “this serious kerfuffle of parsnips” are **grammatical** even though they might not make sense at all, because there's nothing wrong with the structure of the phrase. The same is true for “empty box of matches.”

All that said, many native speakers **would** object if you changed the example slightly:

> This bottle of beer is full of milk.

We call this kind of style error a [garden path sentence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence) because readers are lured down one path (thinking that the bottle is full of beer) and then suddenly surprised by what they find at the end of the sentence (that it's actually full of milk). A garden path sentence forces the reader to suddenly re-interpret the sentence to make sense of it, often requiring a completely different parse of the grammar. For example:

> Time flies like an arrow; fruit flies like a banana.

Comment: +1. I hadn't thought about garden path sentences here at all, but now that you mention it, my reaction when I first read ‘empty box of matches’ was precisely a typical garden-path-sentence reaction.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yep. I think *garden path sentence* usually refers to twisted grammar rather than twisted semantics, so I'm playing a little fast and loose with the term here, but I think it fits better than anything else.

Comment: Would you consider using [empty] 'bottle of milk' for an empty milk bottle?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth “Empty bottle of milk” is fine. Just “bottle of milk” alone is likely to lead down the garden path unless the context makes it obvious that it’s an empty milk bottle.

Comment: "Empty bottle of milk" sounds far from fine to my ears. A 'container of X' means a 'container with a non-zero amount of X' in my book. AHDEL has the definition: **of** 10. Containing or carrying: a basket of groceries. It doesn't have a definition 'designed to contain'. An empty basket of groceries?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This is probably something that varies by dialect. See the discussion under the question itself. Some native speakers find it weird, while others seem to prefer it. I don’t think any native speaker would find it incomprehensible; do you? It’s definitely not a grammatical error, as the syntax is fine.

Comment: I haven't found a dictionary licensing either the required sense of 'of' or the required sense of the putative compound. Until I do, I'll stick with 'as acceptable as _Colorless green ideas ..._'.

Comment: *Of* indicates the [genitive case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genitive_case), which includes **many** relationships, including composition and compounds. Dictionaries don’t get into that kind of subtlety, usage and style guides do.

Comment: It may be a grey area. But usually, the sense of 'of' in these cases implies contents as well as container.  I don't think anyone would argue for 'an empty bucket of water' / 'an empty pan of shelled peas' /  'an empty bowl of soup' / 'an empty plate of chips' / 'an empty tank of fuel' / 'an empty / bare field of wheat'. ODO has as an example of the 'vessel of X' construction: **pan** 1.1: An amount of something contained in a pan:
_a pan of hot water_.

Answer (score 15):

It is grammatically correct. Some may feel it is logically incorrect, but this is mere sophistry. If a box was manufactured to hold matches, it is a matchbox, or box of matches, regardless of whether it holds 100, one, or none.

Comment: It may be “mere sophistry” to you, but it isn't to all of us. The phrasing actually made me pause and go “Huh?” when I read it.

Comment: Both refer to a "box", with the word "match(es)" acting on it like an adjective; a "match box" or a "match-ish box".  The weird thing about that book saying it's incorrect is that, in its language, a phrase like "match box" (technically, "match の box") is extremely common and basic grammar, and it's very easy to translate phrases like that between English and Japanese.  The only question here is if, in English, it's "xy", "x y", or "y of x", and given the meaning of the two words in this case, they all would mean the same thing.

Comment: @Panzercrisis I agree for the most part, although there are often subtle differences in English between *modifier noun* and *noun of modifier,* and this is one of those cases. It’s more obvious when you consider the “bottle of beer full of milk.”

Comment: I know, that's why I mentioned the meaning of the two words in this case.

Comment: "If a box was manufactured to hold matches, it is a [..] box of matches" - by that argument a "box of steel" could be a wooden box made to hold steel. You sure you wouldn't find that slightly surprising? :-)

Comment: @VooMar You are trying to use logic to analyze a human language, but your reasoning is fallacious. The term "box of matches" is relatively common in English and has a set, well-understood, almost idiomatic meaning, whereas the term "box of steel" is in significantly less common use

Comment: Would you consider using [empty] 'bottle of milk' for an empty milk bottle?

Comment: No ,strangely, but I would use milk bottle the same way (or beer bottle, or wine bottle) - these are objects which remain recognizable when empty. Milk bags, too.

Comment: Then I don't understand why those (like myself) who consider 'an empty box of matches' as unacceptable as 'an empty bottle of milk' to be indulging in sophistry.

Comment: I wrote this some time ago, but I don't think that is what I was trying to convey at all. "An empty box of matches" is not sophistry. Claiming the phrase "an empty matchbox" doesn't make sense, is what I termed sophistry.

Comment: When I was teaching, I'd deduct a mark if a pupil in a top set wrote 'empty bucket of water', unless they were obviously trying for a comic effect. I'd also deduct a mark the second time they used 'empty box of matches', as I'd have paralleled these two expressions the first time they used 'empty box of matches'. Correct grammar is only one aspect of good writing / speaking. I remember another contributor here saying 'It's grammatical, but that's about the only good thing you can say about it'. I'll revise my opinion on seeing a grammar or 2 style guides allowing the usage.

Comment: I agree with you completely, really I do. But my point is that there is a difference between a matchbox and a box of matches, and between a milk bottle and a bottle of milk.

Comment: ... and a flower vase and a vase of flowers.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of distinctions to be made here.

- 'grammatical' - this usually means that the syntax makes sense, but that semantically this may or may not be the case. In the classic sentence "Colorless green ideas sleep furiously", each word fits just fine in order, but the sentence doesn't make logical sense.
- 'literally' - some words are used exactly as the are 'The white house needs to be whitewashed because it is dirty' or figuratively 'The White House has too many proclamations' (well  the White House *is* white, but a house really can't speak).
- 'of' - prepositions are notoriously slippery in English. There's an ostensible meaning, but there are just so many uses that are less central or even peripheral. One can put *on* ones pants, but really they're not 'on' you. People can say 'shut up' but what exactly is 'up'? 'Of' is a little more narrow, but the intention can go in many directions. It can mean ownership 'the dog of mine', or a property 'the smell of gasoline' or composition 'the house of cards', or containment 'the bucket of water', or purpose 'the house of detention'

A 'box of matches' may be literally a box made out of matches, but really here it is most naturally assumed to be a box intended as a receptacle for matches. A matchbox is another common way to say it (where 'match' is an attributive noun acting like an adjective) and it is a common pair: an X of Y <-> a Y-X (see Saxon vs Norman genitive).

So the book may be taking a very literal approach, but to a native speaker it is natural to think that a box intended for matches may not actually have any matches in it. And a very natural way to say that is 'The box of matches is empty'.

Comment: This is an extended version of @JamesMcLeod 's answer. I think his is best.

Comment: Does your mention of "shut up" in the paragraph about prepositions mean that you regard the "up" in "shut up" as a preposition? I'd have thought it's an adverb.

Comment: @Andreas yes that was not the best choice because of that complication. 'phrasal verbs', those with unattached prepositions, the prepositions historically come from ... um ... prepositions but act more like, well not exactly prepositionally. But the literalness still stands. The point is that they're not to be taken literally.

Answer (score 4):

> This box of matches is empty

The authors of the English writing guide book argue that if a box contains matches, it cannot, logically speaking, be empty. For if it is empty, it returns to its original state or function prior to it containing the matches, that is, being a box.

Allow me to illustrate by providing a more outlandish example. I have cupboards in my kitchen, in one I keep tea and coffee cups, saucers and teapots; in another there are plates and bowls of different sizes; but in one cupboard I keep only tins of tuna fish. I call it the "cupboard **of** tuna fish". I keep it well-stocked for months on end, until one day I decide that I am tired of eating tuna and I empty the cupboard out. Is that piece of furniture still a "cupboard of tuna fish"? Not if I fill it with pots and pans. Now the cupboard contains something completely different. I could, if I wanted to, refer to it as *"that's the cupboard of pots&pans"*.

However, if that cupboard was manufactured and designed specifically to contain only tuna fish tins (or tuna cans/canned tuna) then it is, for all intents and purposes, a  *tuna fish cupboard*; I could even shorten it to *tuna-cupboard*, and over time I could spell it as one word *"tunacupboard"*.  The noun, *tuna fish* (or *tuna*) describes the purpose or quality of the cupboard, just like a *wine bottle* tells us it is a bottle specifically made for wine; a can containing beer is called *a beer can*; a basket for carrying fruit is *a fruit basket*. The first noun in the following compound words can either describe a quality or the purpose/functionality of the ***last*** noun: *silver photo frame*; *plastic shopping bag*; *16GB memory card*; *all-in-one printer*; *portable air conditioner*; *teapot cosy* (*tea pot* / *tea-pot*) ; etc.

The first noun (or nouns) in a compound word is called an [adjunct noun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) or an attribute noun, it modifies another noun and functions as an adjective, it can be removed leaving the meaning of the second noun intact e.g A <del>silver</del> photo frame (a frame for photos);  a <del>photo</del> frame (now it could be any frame); a <del>all-in-one</del> printer (a machine which prints texts and images on paper).

However, when faced with the term *matchbox* we don't normally think of it as a compound word, i.e., a box for containing matches, we see it as a single word, the union of more than one*free morpheme*, otherwise known as a *[solid compound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_compound#Solid_compound_modifiers)*. In fact Online Etymology tells us that it used to be spelled [*match-box*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=matchbox&searchmode=none), and dates it back to 1786. But nowadays the spelling of *matchbox* is firmly established. Of course it's still "a box **of** matchsticks" (matchsticks = "thin sticks **of** wood for striking a fire".) For the authors to claim that the phrase "This box of matches is empty" is incorrect, is without doubt [prescriptivism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_prescription) of the worst kind.

TL;DR: No, it is not a grammatical error.

> **Compounding and Word Division**
>
> A compound term is a combination of two or more words that, to varying
> degrees, have become unified in form and meaning through frequent use
> together. In many cases only one syllable in the compound is stressed.
> The trend over the years has been for **the English compound to begin as
> two separate words**, then be **hyphenated** and finally, if there is no
> structural impediment to union, **become a single word** written without a
> space or hyphen. Whatever its form, the compound frequently serves to
> avoid circumlocution and create a more concise style.
>
> The existence of three different forms for compounds leads to
> considerable instability and variation in their presentation, and
> hyphenation has become one of the most controversial points of
> editorial style. Dictionaries vary widely in the forms they choose for
> specific compounds: "hot-line" in the Gage Canadian Dictionary, "hot
> line" in the Canadian Dictionary of the English Language and "hotline"
> in The Concise Oxford Dictionary, for example.

<sup>[The Canadian Style](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tcdnstyl-chap?lang=eng&lettr=chapsect2&info0=2): Writing Tools</sup>

Wikipedia says this on prescriptivism

> Although many people would agree that some kinds of prescriptive
> teaching or advice are desirable, prescriptivism is often subject to
> criticism. **Many linguists**, such as Geoffrey Pullum and other posters
> to Language Log, **are highly skeptical of the quality of advice given
> in many usage guides**, including highly regarded books like Strunk and
> White's Elements of Style. In particular, linguists point out that
> **popular books on English usage** written by journalists or novelists
> (e.g. Simon Heffer's Strictly English : the correct way to write ...
> and why it matters) **often make basic errors in linguistic analysis**

[...]

> A second problem with prescription is that prescriptive rules quickly
> become entrenched and it is difficult to change them when the language
> changes. Thus, there is a tendency for prescription to be excessively
> conservative. When in the early 19th century, prescriptive use advised
> against the split infinitive, the main motivation was that this
> construction was not in fact a frequent feature of the varieties of
> English favoured by those prescribing. The prescriptive rule was based
> on a descriptive observation. Today the construction has become common
> in most varieties of English, and a prohibition is no longer supported
> by observation

Comment: I'm not happy with 'However, when faced with the term matchbox we don't normally think of it as a compound word, i.e., a box for containing matches, we see it as a single word'. Compound words _are_ the end product (unified concept), after loose association and gradually gelling collocation.

Comment: Take_ bull's-eye_ as an example. People would, in my estimation, rarely think back to its origins, but would rather have a mental image of a target (or success, if they think in the abstract). 'Thinking of something as a compound word' is ambiguous, as 'compound word' is itself a compound: thinking of it as a word in its own right, without worrying about its etymology, or thinking of it as being the fusion of two elements (your reading here). Tricky. I'd use say 'we don't normally think of this compound in terms of its original elements, i.e., a box for containing matches'.

Comment: But you're right, this is really the crux of the debate:  (1) How unitary is the term 'box of matches'? (2) If 'very', then is it acceptable to use it as an equivalent of 'box made to hold matches' as well as 'box containing some matches'? For many similar expressions (bottle of milk; bucket of water; pan of chips ...) the unitariness is quite high, but the 'for' reading is hardly acceptable.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  Now, I understand your point you were making. Thank you for explaining it clearly. When I see the phrase *a box of matches* I think *matchbox*, to me they are one and the same. A "box of (for) matches" is no different to the normal "matchbox" we used to buy at the tobacconist's. It is not any sized box, although if you wanted to nitpick, I suppose it doesn't exclude that remote possibility. But in the normal world, a *box of matches* = a *matchbox* (one word, one meaning)

Comment: It looks like it's a grey area, as you seem far from alone. But doubtless you'd balk at 'an empty bucket of water'? There seems a gradience. I'd wince at 'an empty bottle of milk'.

Comment: Well thank god she keeps coffee cups in at least one of her cupboards.  If no cups were involved I think this answer would explode in a fit of irony.